# What is the maximum number of lookup relationships an object can have?

Tags: lookup, master-detail

What is the maximum number of lookup relationships an object can have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Master-Detail Relationship Fields, per Object (Standard or Custom) --> 2

Total Relationship Fields (Master-Detail + Lookup), per Object (Standard or Custom) --> 40

Its Like,

> 38 Lookup and 2 MD
>
> 39 Lookup and 1 MD relationship fields on an object

***Please check this link:***

https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=9063A000000DYD0QAO

Comment: This answer can be improved by adding a link/source.

Comment: ok so it means object can have 38 lookup relationship?

Comment: you can have all 40 as Lookup Relationship fields.Please check my updated answer

Comment: @Priya 40 is not a hard limit, though. You can request more with a valid business purpose. For example, we currently have 46 in our production org for Account records.

Answer (score 9):

By default, the system is limited to 40 lookup fields per object, up to two of which may be master-detail relationships if it is a custom object. You can request more than the 40 relationship per object limit if absolutely necessary, although there are performance implications for doing so. The absolute limit that [you can request](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000180846&type=1) is 50.

Comment: Can we not rely on the official *Salesforce Help Documentation*? It claims "[Each custom object can have up to two master-detail relationships and up to 25 total relationships](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.overview_of_custom_object_relationships.htm&type=5#:~:text=Each%20custom%20object%20can%20have%20up%20to%20two%20master%2Ddetail%20relationships%20and%20up%20to%2025%20total%20relationships)". Is information there often obsolete?

Comment: @Bloke probably an oversight. Definitely file a documentation bug. Mistakes are rare, but do happen.

Answer (score 4):

```
                     **Considerations for Relationships**
```

**Relationship Limits**

> Each custom object can have up to two master-detail relationships and
>   many lookup relationships. Each relationship is included in the
>   maximum number of custom fields allowed.

- The Total relationship field included lookup can be 40 by default. As @sfdcFox said, it can be increased if needed by raising a request to salesforce up to 50.

Earlier it was 25, after Summer ’14 Release, The default number of Relationship Fields per object has been increased, from 25 fields to 40 fields.

[image]

reference:-

- https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=custom_field_allocations.htm&type=5
- https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=relationships_considerations.htm&type=5
- http://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer14/release-notes/rn_forcecom_custom_additional.htm

Comment: Your answer isn't quite correct, but it isn't incorrect, either. There is a way to request more than 40 fields if you need them.

Comment: Thanks, @sfdcfox I need to mention your words too in my answer.