# How many LookUp and Master Detail Relationships we can create on a single object?

Tags: lookup, administration, relationships, master-detail, lookup-field

I have came through various articles saying that we create 25 or 40 Lookup relationships on an object but in my org it is showing relationship limit as 50.Can anyone confirm the right number?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The number of Lookup relationship that an object can have are as in today?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/232005/the-number-of-lookup-relationship-that-an-object-can-have-are-as-in-today)

Comment: TL;DR: the limit is 40 but you can ask Salesforce to increase it to 50

Comment: Thanks @fred !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The old default used to be 25, and you'll likely still find older articles and such that describe this limit. This was increased to 40 at some point. However, an organization can request more by following the instructions in [Increase the 'maximum number of custom foreign keys per entity'](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000386135&type=1). This will involve contacting your account executive or technical support, depending on the type of org and when it was created. There is a default limit of 40, which can be increased to 50 by following the instructions for requesting an increase.